# Magento 2: Email template grid is not working

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I'm using Magento 2.2.6. In Email templates, I can't see the grid table. On the other page, the grid table is working fine. I tried to manually remove static content and deploy but not working.
[image: In the Email templates]

[image: The console says]

Comment: same problem, anyone there to help please?